# angular bootstrap scrolling-tabs issues

Tags: angularjs, scroll, angular-ui-tabset

bootstrap-scrolling-tabs to implement scrollable tabs with angular-bootstrap  element.

here is my code

```
 <div class="abc">
            <div class="panel panel-default abcd" >
                <div scrolling-tabs-wrapper>
                    <tabset>
                        <tab class="verticalText" heading="{{evi.evidenceIdentifier}}" ng-repeat="evi in examinationCtrl.getEvidences(examinationCtrl.currentDocument)"
                             select="examinationCtrl.selectEvidence(evi.sss)">
                            <div class="embed-responsive-pdf embed-responsive" ng-style="style()">
                                <div embed-src="{{examinationCtrl.urlForEvidence(evi.sss)}}"
                                     class="embed-responsive-item embed-progress"></div>
                            </div>
                        </tab>
                    </tabset>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I am getting below error when I run this. Any idea whats wrong with this ?

```
Controller 'tabset', required by directive 'tabContentTransclude', can't be found!
```

Comment: Do the tabs show up without `scrolling-tabs-wrapper` ?

Comment: Yes they do showup..

Comment: Ont thing I noticed is if I add my controller on tab element it throws this error. Not sure what is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure: Is the UI Bootstrap library (ui.bootstrap.tabs) added as a dependency?

I've experienced the same error when I extended the scrolling-tabs-wrapper to add new tabs dynamically. As soon as I added a tab to the underlying array the error occured. My search for the error cause brought me here.

I assume the data generated by examinationCtrl.getEvidences() isn't static. Try to provide a static tabs array in your controller and use it in the tab/ng-repeat element and see if that works.

The reason this error is thrown is the following statement in the method "moveTabContentOutsideScrollContainer" in the ElementsHandler:

```
$tabsContainer.find('.tab-content').appendTo($tabsContainer);
```

This moves the element with ".tab-content" out of scope so that the UI Bootstrap controller "tabset" cannot find it anymore. To fix this, I've added an additional function in my custom scrolling-tabs to move it back in scope if I change the initial tabs array.